# Extract text from html tags in an rss feed

Tags: php, xml, rss

We have following rss feed

```
<title>THIS IS THE TITLE</title>
<link>http://www.website.com/....</link>
<description>
  <div class="primary-image">
   <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://website.com/" alt="Drink driving" title="Drink driving" />
  </div>
  <div class="field-group-format group_meta field-group-div group-meta  speed-fast effect-none">
   <span class="field field-name-field-published-date field-type-datetime field-label-hidden">
      <span class="field-item even">
    <span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2014-01-29T17:43:00+00:00">29 Jan, 2014 5:43pm</span>
      </span>
   </span>
   <span class="field field-name-field-author field-type-node-reference field-label-hidden">
      <span class="field-item even"><a href="/authors/joe-finnerty">Joe Finnerty</a></span>
   </span>
  </div>
  <p class="short-desc">TEXT THAT I WANT TO EXTRACT FROM HERE</p>
</description>
```

And i am trying to extract the `<p class="short-desc">TEXT THAT I WANT TO EXTRACT FROM HERE</p>` with the following [this script](http://bavotasan.com/2010/display-rss-feed-with-php/) and checked some questions here but did not find a practical response.

I tried adding

```
$htmlStr = $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$html = new DOMDocument();        
$html->loadHTML($htmlStr);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$desc = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' short-desc')]");
```

before `$item = array (` , within the `foreach` loop but did not work.

but did not do the job. Also instead of 
`&lt;` is replacing `<` AND
`&quot;` is replacing `"` AND
`&gt;` is replacing `>`

Please help i am trying to find an answer for some days now and did not find it.

Comment: You just need the text ? or along with the `<p>` tag ?

Comment: Only the `TEXT THAT I WANT TO EXTRACT FROM HERE` from that specifig p class tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are passing the above HTML content to the `$html` variable ..

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $tag) {
        if ($tag->getAttribute('class') === 'short-desc') {
            echo $tag->nodeValue; //"prints" TEXT THAT I WANT TO EXTRACT FROM HERE
         }
    }
```

Comment: could you please post entire script based on that one from [the link](http://bavotasan.com/2010/display-rss-feed-with-php/), I am not catching exactly how to link them. I am a noob in OOP and DOM

Comment: I wanted to say based on this one http://bavotasan.com/2010/display-rss-feed-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to remove tags from feeds so you can try like this:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
?>
```

output will be:

```
Test paragraph. Other text
```

For more info:https://www.php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 0):

why not use regex?

```
$strRegex = '%<p class="short-desc">(.+?)</p>%s';

if (preg_match_all($strRegex, $strContent, $arrMatches))
{
var_dump($arrMatches[1][0]);
}
```

and to get the content use

```
$path = 'path/to/file';
$strContent = file_get_contents($path);
```